# In VUE.js my local font is not working. I get error messeage in npm

Tags: vue.js, webpack, fonts, webpack-file-loader

I would like to import a ttf font file in to my VUE js file with webpack file loader and I get this error in npm. Im imported to the main.js my fonts.sccs where Im declarete the fontface.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX8kW.png)

```
"Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { auxiliaryComment?, chunkFilename?, crossOriginLoading?, jsonpScriptType?, chunkLoadTimeout?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolLineToLine?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, filename?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateFunction?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, jsonpFunction?, library?, libraryTarget?, libraryExport?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, umdNamedDefine? }
   -> Options affecting the output of the compilation. `output` options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk."
```

and here is my webpack.config code :

```
{
        test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
          },
        },
      }
```

My package json is working well with the file-loader.

Comment: Please include the error message in your question *as text*

Comment: I already changed^^